# instagram.bind.InstagramClientError: Unable to parse response, not valid JSON

Tags: python, json, instagram

Made myself a simple Instagram client to make authenticated requests to their API. However, running it keeps throwing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "request-ig-data.py", line 24, in <module>
   recent_media = api.user_recent_media(user_id=user_id, count=50)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 151, in _call
return method.execute()
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 143, in execute
content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 99, in _do_api_request
raise InstagramClientError('Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.')
instagram.bind.InstagramClientError: Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.
```

Ok, so the response isn't JSON (despite the fact that I'd expect it to be given that's Instagram's doc'd reponse format), but why? Code is a pretty basic implementation of python-instagram - followed their docs and have tried converting response to JSON but still getting same err. Here's code:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
import httplib2
import json
import sys

client_id = '[...]'
client_secret = '[...]'
redirect_uri = 'https://mycallback.com'
scope = ''
user_id = '1034466'  # starbucks

api = InstagramAPI(client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret,redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
redirect_uri = api.get_authorize_login_url(scope = scope)

print "Visit this page and authorize access in your browser:\n", redirect_uri

code = raw_input("Paste in code in query string after redirect: ").strip()

access_token = api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code)

print "access token:\n", access_token

api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
recent_media, next = api.user_recent_media(user_id=user_id, count=50)
for media in recent_media:
   print media.text
```

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
access_token = api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code)
```

Is better put in this way:

```
access_token, user_info = api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code)
```

That would split out the access token from the user info. That way you can keep this line the same:

```
client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
```

Comment: I should also note, I received this same error, but realized it was because I was attempting to use the username and not user-id (which can be retrieved based on username via the user_search method: `user = api.user_search('username')[0].id`).

Comment: bshur2008 is totally correct - I was sending a username not user id as well

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. `api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)` should be `api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token[0])` to pass the access token and not the full object.